# How to transform a json to flat using JOLT?

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

I just need to make the attributes element to be on the same level with the id.

I am just having an issue to copy the attributes to be on the same level.

This is my sample JSON

```
{
  "data" : [ {
    "type" : "types",
    "id" : "CYY7",
    "attributes" : {
      "description" : null,
      "color" : "#dfc12d",
      "duration" : 15,
      "created_at" : "2017-01-10T04:51:22Z",
      "updated_at" : "2017-01-10T04:51:22Z",
      "slug" : "15min",
      "active" : false,
      "location" : null
    }
  }, {
    "type" : "types",
    "id" : "BGER",
    "attributes" : {
      "description" : null,
      "color" : "#8989fc",
      "duration" : 30,
      "created_at" : "2017-01-10T04:51:22Z",
      "updated_at" : "2017-01-10T04:51:22Z",
      "slug" : "30min",
      "active" : true,
      "location" : null
    }
  }
```

This is my sample transformation.

```
[{
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
        "data": {
            "*": {
                "id": "event_type[&1].id",
                "type": "event_type[&1].type",
                "attributes": "event_type[&1].attributes[&1].description"
            }
        }
    }
}]
```

The desired output would be

```
{
  "event_type" : [ {
    "type" : "types",
    "id" : "CYY7",
    "description" : null,
    "color" : "#dfc12d",
    "duration" : 15,
  }, {
    "type" : "types",
    "id" : "BGER",
    "description" : null,
    "color" : "#8989fc",
    "duration" : 30,
  }]
}
```

Comment: This is the part which I am having troubles with: **"attributes": "event_type[&1].attributes[&1].description"**

Answer (score 4):

Try with this **`Jolt Spec`**:

```
[{
  "operation": "shift",
  "spec": {
    "data": {
      "*": {
        "id": "event_type[&1].id",
        "type": "event_type[&1].type",
        "attributes": {
          "description": "event_type[&2].description",
          "color": "event_type[&2].color",
          "duration": "event_type[&2].duration"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}]
```

***Output:***

```
{
  "event_type" : [ {
    "id" : "CYY7",
    "type" : "types",
    "description" : null,
    "color" : "#dfc12d",
    "duration" : 15
  }, {
    "id" : "BGER",
    "type" : "types",
    "description" : null,
    "color" : "#8989fc",
    "duration" : 30
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Hii @Shu 
Thanks for the response. Silly me. I need to get rid of event_type completely and remain with simply {{"id":"aksjakj"},{"id":"saasa"}}. How can i achieve this.?

Comment: Hii @Shu. Thanks i have figured it out on my own. Just remove the event_type .. :smile.. Thanks